# Using simple_forms simple_field_for with a multipart file uploader for Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, simple-form

I am creating a blog that allows me to upload multiple image files when I create the blog post. I am using Rails 4 with the simple form gem. I am unable to get the file input to allow the selection of multiple files, though the upload of a single file works just fine.

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2, class: "white"><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li, class: "white"><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :subtitle %>
  <%= f.input :author %>
  <%= f.input :content, as: :text %>
  <%= f.input :publish, as: :select %>
  <%= f.association :tags, as: :check_boxes %>

  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Upload Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Link to Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Quote</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :post_attachments do |p| %>
         <div class="field">
           <%= p.input :media, as: :file, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[media][]" %>
         </div>
       <% end %>
       <div class="actions"></br>
          <%= f.button :submit %>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :video_link %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :video_link %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions"></br>
          <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :quote_text %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :quote_text %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :quote_author %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :quote_author %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :quote_source %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :quote_source %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions"></br>
          <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
</script>
<% end %>
```

I suspect that the "multipart" attribute is not entered properly. I can't seem to find any documentation on this other than this statement on the [simple_form wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#extra-helpers):

"Wrapper to use Simple Form inside a default rails form. It works in the same way that the fields_for Rails helper, but change the builder to use the SimpleForm::FormBuilder."

I don't understand what specifically to do here. I would appreciate some guidance on this issue.

UPDATE: Here is my controller code

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  layout :resolve_layout

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def list
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def show
    @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        if (@post_attachments != nil)
          params[:post_attachments]['media'].each do |a|
            @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:media => a, :post_id => @post.id)
          end
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
    # @post.save
    # respond_with(@post)
  end

  def update
    @post.update(post_params)
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :author, :content, :publish, :quote_author, :quote_text, :quote_source, :video_link, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :media])
    end

    def resolve_layout
      case action_name
      when "edit", "new", "create", "index"
        "full_width"
      when "show", "list"
        "blog_rt"
      else
        "base"
    end
  end
end
```

posts_attachments_controller.rb

```
  class PostAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post_attachment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @post_attachments = PostAttachment.all
    respond_with(@post_attachments)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@post_attachment)
  end

  def new
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new
    respond_with(@post_attachment)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new(post_attachment_params)
    @post_attachment.save
    respond_with(@post_attachment)
  end

  def update
    @post_attachment.update(post_attachment_params)
    respond_with(@post_attachment)
  end

  def destroy
    @post_attachment.destroy
    respond_with(@post_attachment)
  end

  private
    def set_post_attachment
      @post_attachment = PostAttachment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_attachment_params
      params.require(:post_attachment).permit(:post_id, :media)
    end
end
```

Here are my models:

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_attachments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments
end
```

post_attachment.rb

```
class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :media, MediaUploader
    belongs_to :post 
end
```

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the controller and model code.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing this line

```
<%= p.input :media, as: :file, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[media][]" %>
```

to

```
<%= p.input :media, as: :file, :multiple => true, name: "post[post_attachments_attributes][][media]" %>
```

***Update:***

You should change `:media` to `:media => []` in your `post_params` method of your `posts_controller` to save multiple values.

```
def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :author, :content, :publish, :quote_author, :quote_text, :quote_source, :video_link, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :media => []])
end
```

[**Source**](http://alagram.github.io/blog/2013/11/04/uploading-multiple-files-with-carrierwave-and-a-nested-form/)

Comment: That did not work. However, I found that this at least lets me select multiple files: `<%= p.input :media, as: :file, :input_html => { :multiple => true }, name: "post_attachments[media][]" %>`  But it does not actually save multiple files. It only saves one file.

Comment: @acoustic_north Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: those changes did not work. I am no longer able to select multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
<%= i.input :media, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true, name: "post_attachments[media][]" } %>
```

This should solve the issue.